# Transfer mathematical calculation on Data Studio

Tags: regex, looker-studio

I've been thinking about how to calculate NSS on DATA studio. I have a column on my spreadsheet with a score that looks like this

**Score**
9
9
6
6
6

I have to use the formula **SUM(9,10)-SUM(0-6)/total records** to calculate the NSS but can't make it work:

```
VAR Calculate_9
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(SCORE, '9') THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END

VAR Calculate_6
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(SCORE, '9') THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END

VAR Total
Count(Score)
```

```
Var Count_9
COUNT(Calculate_9)

Var Count_6
COUNT(Calculate_6)
```

```
Var Calculate_9
(9*Count_9)

Var Calculate_6
(6*Count_6)


((SUM(Calculate_9))-(SUM(Calculate_9)))/Total
```

It is not working, any help? please

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to incorporate the [`IF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10468770) function and then set the field type to `Numeric > Percent`:

### 1) % >= 9

```
COUNT(IF(SCORE >= 9 AND SCORE <= 10, SCORE, NULL)) / COUNT(SCORE)
```

### 2) % <= 6

```
COUNT(IF(SCORE >= 0 AND SCORE <= 6, SCORE, NULL)) / COUNT(SCORE)
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/6782f6e3-f97a-4b83-b892-58db532d67fe) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tf2YohiyE_ZAV0HLhVcM0DyJJr2nvjVYig4BSA7P5Bc/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]